# Assign value (array) to a value of a variable in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an array called `comerciosAMostrar`  , and a selector what is taking the value of it called
`$('#numeroComercioPillbox').val()`, i just want to assign the array to the value, but it's throwing me an error like

> Invalid left-hand side in assignment

Do you know why?

```
$('#numeroComercioPillbox').val() = comerciosAMostrar
```

Comment: The correct syntax would be `$('#numeroComercioPillbox').val(comerciosAMostrar)` - however this raises additional issues. `val()` accepts a string, not an array, so what output are you expecting to see in the HTML? You'd most likely need to `join(',')` the array at least.

Comment: You can't assign to function call results `func() = something`

Answer (score 0):

$('#numeroComercioPillbox') what element is this? , and what is the output you need to display? please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is assigning an array to a function call.

The right syntax would be -

```
$('#numeroComercioPillbox').val(<some-value>);
```

`<some-value>` should be a string.

Since you're trying to assign an array, it might be better to `JSON.stringify()` it as -

```
$('#numeroComercioPillbox').val(JSON.stringify(comerciosAMostrar));
```

Update:
Instead of `JSON.stringify()`, you could also `.join()` as Rory in the comments suggested.

```
$('#numeroComercioPillbox').val(comerciosAMostrar.join(', '));
```